# In a MySQL Master/Slave replication, what would happen if I write to the master table and in slave table is drop?

Tags: mysql, replication

In a MySQL Master/Slave replication, what would happen if I write to the master table and in slave table is drop ?

Comment: here write mean update (if i do update in master what result come in salve)

Comment: The question is not clear.Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If the Slaves do not find 'DROP TABLE' command in the Master's binary logs, it cannot run the DROP TABLE either DROP TABLE command has not been run on Master.